# Symmetric django model

Tags: django, orm, symmetric

I want to create a model, which is symmetric on two fields. Let's call the model Balance:

```
class Balance (models.Model):
    payer = models.ForeignKey(auth.User, ...)
    payee = models.ForeignKey(auth.User, ...)
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)
```

It should have the following property:

```
balance_forward = Balance.objects.get(payer=USER_1, payee=USER_2)
balance_backward = Balance.objects.get(payer=USER_2, payee=USER_1)

balance_forward.amount == -1 * balance_backward.amount
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: So `USER_2` can never pay to `USER_1`, only `USER_!` to `USER_2`?

Comment: No, they both can pay each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up with the following solution. Feel free to suggest other solutions.

```
class SymmetricPlayersQuerySet (models.query.QuerySet):

    def do_swap(self, obj):
        obj.payer, obj.payee = obj.payee, obj.payer
        obj.amount *= -1

    def get(self, **kwargs):
        swap = False
        if "payer" in kwargs and "payee" in kwargs:
            if kwargs["payer"].id > kwargs["payee"].id:
                swap = True
                kwargs["payer"], kwargs["payee"] = \
                    kwargs["payee"], kwargs["payer"]

        obj = super().get(**kwargs)

        if swap:
            self.do_swap(obj)

        return obj

    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if (
            ("payer" in kwargs and "payee" not in kwargs) or
            ("payee" in kwargs and "payer" not in kwargs)
        ):
            if "payee" in kwargs:
                key, other = "payee", "payer"
            else:
                key, other = "payer", "payee"

            constraints = (
                models.Q(payer=kwargs[key]) |
                models.Q(payee=kwargs[key])
            )

            queryset = super().filter(constraints)
            for obj in queryset:
                if getattr(obj, other) == kwargs[key]:
                    self.do_swap(obj)

            return queryset

        return super().filter(*args, **kwargs)


class BalanceManager (models.Manager.from_queryset(SymmetricPlayersQuerySet)):
    pass


class Balance (models.Model):

    objects = BalanceManager()

    payer = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='balance_payer',
    )
    payee = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='balance_payee',
    )
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=1000, default=0)

    def do_swap(self):
        self.payer, self.payee = self.payee, self.payer
        self.amount *= -1

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        swap = False
        if self.payer.id > self.payee.id:
            swap = True
            self.do_swap()

        result = super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if swap:
            self.do_swap()

        return result

    def refresh_from_db(self, *args, **kwargs):
        swap = False
        if self.payer.id > self.payee.id:
            swap = True

        super().refresh_from_db(*args, **kwargs)

        if swap:
            self.do_swap()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate on the `Balance` objects with:

```
from django.db.models import Case, F, Sum, When
from django.conf import settings


class Balance(models.Model):
    payer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, …)
    payee = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, …)
    amount = models.DecimalField(…)

    def get_balance(cls, payer, payee):
        return cls.objects.filter(
            Q(payer=payer, payee=payee) | Q(payer=payee, payee=payer)
        ).aggregate(
            total=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(payer=payer, then=F('amount')),
                    otherwise=-F('amount'),
                    output_field=DecimalField(…),
                )
            )
        )['total']
```

This will look for all `Balance`s between the `payer` and the `payee`, and subtract the ones in the opposite direction. The `Balance.get_balance(payer=foo, payee=bar)` will thus determine the total flow from `foo` to `bar`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thanks, Willem! Interesting solution, I've learned new tricks from it. However, there are 2 disadvantages of your solution. Firstly, your solution is memory inefficient. It uses the whole player-to-player matrix and values can only increase with each payment. Secondly, I'd prefer to use the model as a regular django model, without additional workarounds. Thanks for your suggestions, I appreciate your help anyway!